# IPHONE: variables in instruments

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

When using instruments to debug memory allocation, you can see how much an allocation is using, its address in memory, etc. My question is: is there any way to know which variable/object in your code corresponds to that memory allocation, inside instruments?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the main window the category column is the type of object. if you click on the arrow that appears beside the object type it will give you a list of all instances, I suggest looking at one where you program is the responsible library.  Then click the split window button at the bottom, 6th from the left.  Pause the instrument tool so you can scroll the stack trace.